# Parsing a dataframe string for a column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe column with a strings representing a paths.  I'd like to use some of that path as the value in another column.

The strings are similar to the following and in a Column Titled `'Image Location'`

```
C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 4\D2\Image9.tif
C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 4\D6\Image7.tif
C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 4\D7\Image3.tif
...
C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 6\D2\Image7.tif
C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 6\D2\Image1.tif
C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 6\D2\Image6.tif
C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 6\D3\Image4.tif
C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 6\D3\Image9.tif
...
C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 8\D1\Image4.tif
C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 8\D1\Image9.tif
C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 8\D1\Image3.tif
C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 8\D2\Image7.tif
C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 8\D2\Image1.tif
C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 8\D2\Image6.tif
```

Right now I'm doing the following :

```
df['Interval'] = df['Image Location'].str.split('\\').apply(lambda x: x[5])
df['Device'] = df['Image Location'].str.split('\\').apply(lambda x: x[6])
```

This clearly requires the path not to change very much because I'm counting the number of `\` to find the Interval and Device values.

I'm wondering if there's a more robust way to do this.  For instance, maybe find a pattern such as `Day #` and `D#`  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to depend on the number of `\`'s, you can do something like this:

```
df['Image Location'].map(lambda x: re.findall(r'(?<=Day )[0-9]+', x)).map(lambda x: np.nan if not x else x[0])
df['Image Location'].map(lambda x: re.findall(r'(?<=D)[0-9]+', x)).map(lambda x: np.nan if not x else x[0])
```

This will first find substring `Day` (or `D`) and return the numbers that immediately follow that. So, it assumes there is no other such pattern anywhere else in the string because it will pick up all patterns like `D` followed by any number of digits.

UPDATE:
Looks like it's easier to use `Series.str.extract` as @MaxU suggested.
Here it goes:

```
df['Image Location'].str.extract('[Day ]([0-9]+)')
df['Image Location'].str.extract('[D]([0-9]+)')
```

Comment: This was the direction I was thinking originally.  I'm not sure which solution is better, this or the one from @MaxU  This seems like it would be robust to some path change between \Day # and \D# e.g. `C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 8\run 1\D2\Image6.tif` but that's unlikely to happen.  Max's solution is robust to the Interval changing from Days to Hours `C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\48 hr\D2\Image6.tif`  That is probably more likely, but both are great solutions!

Answer (score 1):

i would use [Series.str.extract()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) method:

```
In [40]: df[['Interval','Device']] = \
             df['Image Location'].str.extract(r'([^\\]+)\\([^\\]+)\\[^\\]+$', expand=True)

In [41]: df
Out[41]:
                                                 Image Location Interval Device
0   C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 4\D2\Image9.tif    Day 4     D2
1   C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 4\D6\Image7.tif    Day 4     D6
2   C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 4\D7\Image3.tif    Day 4     D7
3   C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 6\D2\Image7.tif    Day 6     D2
4   C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 6\D2\Image1.tif    Day 6     D2
5   C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 6\D2\Image6.tif    Day 6     D2
6   C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 6\D3\Image4.tif    Day 6     D3
7   C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 6\D3\Image9.tif    Day 6     D3
8   C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 8\D1\Image4.tif    Day 8     D1
9   C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 8\D1\Image9.tif    Day 8     D1
10  C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 8\D1\Image3.tif    Day 8     D1
11  C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 8\D2\Image7.tif    Day 8     D2
12  C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 8\D2\Image1.tif    Day 8     D2
13  C:\Users\Chris H\Desktop\20161017HCT116\Day 8\D2\Image6.tif    Day 8     D2
```

[Here is parsed and explained RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/mz3uLv/1)

The RegEx in this solution assumes that you last two path parts (directories) are always: `Interval` and `Device` correspondingly.

It does NOT matter how many `\` (back-slashes) are there at the beginning of the path

Comment: Very interesting solution.